# How to assign methods to a dynamic created Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following class which is the class for creating a gridview dynamic:

```
    public class DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        string _ColName;
        DataControlRowType _rowType;
        int _Count;
        int _Kind;

        public DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate(string ColName, DataControlRowType RowType, int Kind)
        {
            _ColName = ColName;
            _rowType = RowType;
            _Kind = Kind;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            switch (_rowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    if (_Kind == 0)
                    {
                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.lbl_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    }
                    else
                    if (_Kind == 1)
                    {
                        ImageButton vImageButton = new ImageButton();
                        vImageButton.ID = "btnGetVoucher";
                        vImageButton.CommandArgument = string.Format("<%# Eval({0}) %>", "Voucher");
                        vImageButton.CssClass = "divButton";
                        vImageButton.Height = 25;
                        vImageButton.Width = 25;
                        vImageButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnGetVoucher_Command);
                        vImageButton.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.imgBtn_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(vImageButton);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and the following c# code for assigning methods runtime to the imagebutton which I have created in a column:

```
        protected void btnGetVoucher_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
        }

        protected void gridview_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ImageButton vImageButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnGetVoucher");
                vImageButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnGetVoucher_Command);
            }
        }
```

and the creating of the gridcolumn is as follows:

```
    GridView vGridView = new GridView();
    vGridView.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gridview_RowCreated);
    vTemplateField = new TemplateField();
    vTemplateField.HeaderTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.Header, 0);
    vTemplateField.ItemTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.DataRow, 1);
    vGridView.Columns.Add(vTemplateField);
```

And at last the databind here:

```
    private void imgBtn_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        btn.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "Voucher").ToString();
    }
```

But I can't step into the method `btnGetVoucher_Command` :-( I think that everything has been made correctly - but there must be something I have missed somewhere...

I can access the button in my Row_Created routine - but afterwards not use the GetVoucherCommand :-( the event is not fired :-(

So my question is why can't I step into that routine?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

**Update:**
The full class is here...

```
    public class DynamicGridViewTextTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        string _ColNameText;
        DataControlRowType _rowType;

        public DynamicGridViewTextTemplate(string ColNameText, DataControlRowType RowType)
        {
            _ColNameText = ColNameText;
            _rowType = RowType;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            switch (_rowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    Literal lc = new Literal();
                    lc.Text = "<b>" + _ColNameText + "</b>";
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    ImageButton vImageButton = new ImageButton();
                    vImageButton.ID = "btnGetVoucher";
                    vImageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Icons/icons8-download-from-the-cloud-50.png";
                    vImageButton.PostBackUrl = "#DownloadVoucher";
                    vImageButton.CommandArgument = string.Format("<%# Eval({0}) %>", "Voucher");
                    vImageButton.ToolTip = "Se og download bilag";
                    vImageButton.CssClass = "divButton";
                    vImageButton.Height = 25;
                    vImageButton.Width = 25;
                    vImageButton.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.imgBtn_DataBind);
                    vImageButton.CommandName = "DownloadVoucher";
                    vImageButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnGetVoucher_Command);
                    container.Controls.Add(vImageButton);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void imgBtn_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            btn.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, _ColNameText).ToString();
        }

    }

    public class DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        string _ColNameText;
        DataControlRowType _rowType;

        public DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate(string ColNameText, DataControlRowType RowType)
        {
            _ColNameText = ColNameText;
            _rowType = RowType;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            switch (_rowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    Literal lc = new Literal();
                    lc.Text = "<b>" + _ColNameText + "</b>";
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    ImageButton vImageButton = new ImageButton();
                    vImageButton.ID = "btnGetVoucher";
                    vImageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Icons/icons8-download-from-the-cloud-50.png";
                    vImageButton.PostBackUrl = "#DownloadVoucher";
                    vImageButton.CommandArgument = string.Format("<%# Eval({0}) %>", "Voucher");
                    vImageButton.ToolTip = "Se og download bilag";
                    vImageButton.CssClass = "divButton";
                    vImageButton.Height = 25;
                    vImageButton.Width = 25;
                    vImageButton.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.imgBtn_DataBind);
                    vImageButton.CommandName = "DownloadVoucher";
                    vImageButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnGetVoucher_Command);
                    container.Controls.Add(vImageButton);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void btnGetVoucher_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
        }

        private void imgBtn_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            btn.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, _ColNameText).ToString();
        }

    }
```

The events is here...

```
protected void gridview_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton vImageButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnGetVoucher");
    }
}

protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton vImageButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnGetVoucher");
    }
}

protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DownloadVoucher")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridView grid = sender as GridView;
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
        ImageButton vImageButton = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("btnGetVoucher");
    }
}
```

The creating of the gridview is here...

```
GridView vGridView = new GridView();
vGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
vGridView.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
vGridView.ShowHeader = true;
vGridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C6E0B4");
vGridView.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

vGridView.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gridview_RowCreated);
vGridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gridview_RowDataBound);
vGridView.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(gridview_RowCommand);

vTemplateField = new TemplateField();
vTemplateField.HeaderTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.Header);
vTemplateField.ItemTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.DataRow);
vGridView.Columns.Add(vTemplateField);
```

Answer (score 0):

micheal.

1. in this code, i can't see event handling code in InstantiateIn method.

ex) like this.

```
lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.btnGetVoucher_Command);
```

2. DynamicGridViewTextTemplate class constructor args are 3 count.

but, when using DynamicGridViewTextTemplate constructor,

used only 2 count args.

where is kind?

try it.

```
vTemplateField.HeaderTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.Header, 0);
vTemplateField.ItemTemplate = new DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate("Voucher", DataControlRowType.DataRow, 1);
```

3. best example in msdn

https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for writing :-)
Yes - you are rightl, I have missed the Kind parameter - but if I set this parameter I still can't access the commandargument runtime :-(
Do you have any further ideas how to acess the commandargument?

Comment: I have now updated the code with the kind parameter and added the databinding routine...

Comment: Have you applied an event handler? not applied btnGetVoucher_Command handler in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for making a comment again :-) I have now added this eventhandler - but still with no success :-(

Comment: only using kind 1? not handling in kind 0

Comment: Yes for the moment I only use kind=1

Comment: could i see the full code? or do you have a github?

Comment: Thanks for commenting again :-) I have now offered my full code ...

Comment: where is DynamicGridViewImageButtonTemplate? using GridViewRowEventHandler

Comment: Im sorry - Im confused now :-( I have tried so much until now ...

Comment: Have you applied an event handler? not applied btnGetVoucher_Command handler in your code again.

Comment: I have now added this eventhandler - I have totally forgotten it :-( I am really glad that you are trying to help me :-) As mentioned earlier I have tried so much until now with no success ...

Comment: Still not? or Success?

Comment: Unfortunately - Still not success :-(

Comment: Yes I have set breakpoints into all the routines - but the application does not stop there :-(

Comment: so sorry. I think I can only help you up to this point. I think you should start with the msdn code, then modify it one by one.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to try to help me... :-)